# Can't change button's background color in XML .Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, button, colors, tablelayout

[image: Android studio screenshot]

I created `TableLayout` then buttons. The button's color was automatically set purple. So I can't change them right now.  It's my first time here.

Answer (score 45):

don't use anything else use

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
<!-- attributes-->
/>
```

instead of one

```
<Button
<!--attributes-->
/>
```

every thing will work nicely.

Happy coding.

Comment: Worked for me. But can you please elaborate what is the issue with the "Button"? Thanks

Answer (score 27):

It's purple because of default background Tint color.
You can :
change **app:backgroundTint ** instad of **android:backgroundColor** . In this case your backgroundTint will appear instead of background color

OR

add

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

and after that your background color will appear.

**OR**

You can change the default theme in android manifest .
For example :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

or

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 20):

Android default color is **Purple** in the latest Android Studio version.
To change the color of the **Button**, you need to add a single line of code in the XML i.e.

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

That's all!

Answer (score 6):

Add the attribute:

`app:backgroundTint="@null"`

Answer (score 5):

You might be using `targetSdkVersion` 30

Solution: change the theme.xml style from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, I tried almost everything and nothing worked! Seems like something has changed in Android Studio 4.1.1? idk.

[MY SOLUTION] So I used TextView instead of Button and set custom background and it worked for me :/ Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You can change style from design editor as shown in below image**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As some other guys mentioned, it might be that your theme overrides your button color

**materialButtonStyle** in particular

You can

- either change your theme to **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar** (or something like this)
- or override **materialButtonStyle** parameter

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" />
    <style name="Theme.GradientTest" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- Other params here. -->
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use this button

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your button xml

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

And replace it with

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy. You should create a shape in XML. Set background to that shape then set background with that XML.

Answer (score 0):

it worked well with the update on 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'

or

do it programmatically : myButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.my_background)

both options, you'll need to set app:backgroundTint property as null

app:backgroundTint="@null"

check the next link: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889

Comment: app:backgroundTint="@null" did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to res-values-themes-themes
you will find two themes. one is when dark mode is activated. Go and change the one in dark mode. what could be happening is you have a different style for dark mode.
I really hope it was easy to understand since english is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue. In the xml replace background in "android:background="@android:color/black" with backgroundTint "android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
inside the button tag, use

```
android:backgroundTint="#ccc"
```

replace #ccc in the above line with hex code for your preferred color. This should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

use hexcode directly to change the background

`android:backgroundTint="#A9A9A9"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `setBackgroundColor()` on your button in the button click listener