# How to remove default background tint of button

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I came across this issue when I was trying to create a custom button. I have created a simple drawable and I set it as the background of my button. But that doesn't work, at least not directly, first i have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null`  (which I got to know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715253/cant-change-buttons-background-color-in-xml-android-studio))

*So what I want to do is set the default backgroundTint as 'null'. So where do I add this? Or any other way to achieve this?*

**Update:**

I've found a solution to this and I've posted it.

Comment: Please add the XML part where you define your Button.

Comment: check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color/63331089#63331089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a lot of researching and experimenting, I've concluded that the default purple tint on buttons is due to the themes.xml file. The Styles tag inside the themes.xml generally has this as the first line for me:

`<style name="Theme.appName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

Now the reason it uses the purple tint on buttons is due to the "parent".
**So changing the parent in the style tag of themes.xml to**  `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`  **does the trick.** It sets the plain grey button as the default button for that project which you might've seen in many tutorials

Comment: Soved my problem. After 1hr of debugging

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your theme

you can just change **materialButtonStyle** parameter
as I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74862273/12084802